# How to use onclick window.open in Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I use Alpine to fetch API. A button allows users to copy the text and I'd like to add the `onclick` attribute.

HTML code:

```
<div x-data="{ code: 'SALE10' }">
  <button x-clipboard="code" @click="$tooltip('Copied')" onclick="setTimeout('window.open(\'https://target-domain.com/\')', 900);">Copy this</button>
</div>
```

in which, I use the [clipboard](https://github.com/ryangjchandler/alpine-clipboard) `x-clipboard` to target and copy `code`. I use the [Alpine tooltip](https://alpinejs.dev/component/tooltip) to show the notification after clicking. Then, open a new tab `https://target-domain.com`. The `site.url` will return a URL, and I also tried:

```
:onclick="setTimeout('window.open(\'site.url\')', 900);
```

Please let me know how to make it works. In general, I'd like to create a button that a user will click to copy the code and the link will be opened automatically. Any better recommendation? Thanks much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

With Alpine.js the [`@click` attribute](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on) is literally the `onclick`. You can provide multiple statements there:

```
<div x-data="{ url: 'http://your.url' }">
  <button x-clipboard="url" @click="$tooltip('Copied'); setTimeout(() => {window.open(url)}, 900)">Copy this</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's sth wrong in my code and I edited it: `x-data="{ code: 'SALE10'}`  `x-clipboard="code"` instead of `url` .
However, your code still works well due to `setTimeout(() => {window.open(url)}, 900)` 
Thanks for your answer! I, a web builder with low-code, learn more about Alpine via demos.